# General error: 1005 when creating a key constraint - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

When trying to add a foreign key constraint in Laravel I am getting the following error.

```
[PDOException]                                                                                
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'ts.#sql-5769_62' (errno: 150)
```

I have 2 tables, `users` and `teams`. The relationship is teams can have many users and users have one team.

Users

```
$table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('team_id');

        $table->string('name', 255);
        $table->string('username', 32)->unique();
        $table->string('email', 320);
        $table->string('password', 64);

        $table->foreign('team_id')->references('id')->on('teams');


        $table->timestamps();
```

Teams

```
        $table->increments('id');

        $table->string('team_name', 255);
        $table->string('website', 255);

        $table->timestamps();
```

What am I doing wrong? Also this is my first time using migrations so any help in pointing out silly errors is welcomed.

Comment: "When trying to add a foreign key constraint" --- how do you do that?

Comment: Sorry I don't follow?

Comment: Seems that why doesn't it.

Answer (score 9):

Try to specify `unsigned` for `team_id`:

```
$table->integer('team_id')->unsigned();
```

You primary key `$table->increments('id');` is an unsigned integer, so the foreign key `$table->integer('team_id');` should match it's type.

Quoted from [Laravel docs](http://four.laravel.com/docs/schema):

> Note: When creating a foreign key that references an incrementing
>   integer, remember to always make the foreign key column unsigned.

#### Update

Also make sure you create the `team` table first, so the Schema builder don't attempt to create a foreign key on a non existing table.

Comment: It's not unsigned on the `teams` table

Comment: "You primary key $table->increments('id'); is an unsigned integer" --- what makes thinking you so?

Comment: Columns created with `$table->increments('id');` are always unsigned. This is how the schema builder works.

Comment: is it a laravel feature? What is the exact column definition in this case (I cannot find it in documentation)?

Comment: Found it: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php#L349 and it's weird

Comment: This how the Schema builder works. It will automatically set increments to integer and unsigned. When using an auto incrementing column, negative values doesn't make sense. Please see my update.

Comment: "negative values doesn't make sense" --- they do. Being autoincrement doesn't automatically mean the column is positive.

Comment: Well in most situations they are positive. But yes, there are cases when they make sense. However I never met some situation :) I mean why should a user or a team have a negative id?

Comment: anyway, +1d you since it looks like an answer :-)

Comment: this doesn't fix the error.  [Exception]                                                                                                                            
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'ts.#sql-5769_64' (errno: 150) (SQL: alter table `users` add constraint  
   users_team_id_foreign foreign key (`team_id`) references `teams` (`id`)) (Bindings: array (                                           
  ))

Comment: No, database is empty.

Comment: Just another hint. You should create the `team` table first, maybe the schema builder can't reference the `team` table when creating the `users` table, because `team` table doesn't exists yet. I'm not sure if the schema builder can handle this automatically.

Comment: @TamasPap This seemed to fix my error, if you edit the post I will mark as answered.