# Errno: 150 "Laravel Migration Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Tags: php, laravel

Code for users

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('user_role')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Code for user roles

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('user_roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('user_role');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `sms`.`#sql-1718_62` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `users` add constraint `users_role_id_foreign` foreign key (`role_id`) references `user_role` (`id`) on delete cascade)

Comment: even add the $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned(); also have the error. May I know what the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to reference a foreign key please don't create it with

```
$table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
```

instead you should use

```
$table->unsignedInteger('role_id');
```

This is related to the docs from the Migrations Part: [Laravel Migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations).

So your new statement should end up looking like

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->unsignedInteger('role_id');
        $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('user_role')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**Edit:**

After the author has added the migration code of the *user_role* table the problem is clear.

The table the author is refering to is called *user_roles* and not as mentioned in the foreign key migration *user_role*.

So here is the migration that should work for the *users* table.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->unsignedInteger('role_id');
        $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('user_roles')->onDelete('cascade'); // change this line
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
   });
 }
```

The naming is related to the Laravel Naming convention, where all tables are named in plural while all models are named in singular.

**Edit 2:**

OP mentioned that he had the migrations in the wrong order, what was the reason for the not working migration.

The *users* table got created before the *user_roles* table. Thats why the foreign key causes the error.

Hope this helps you out! If you got any more problems please let me know!

Comment: Hm, I don't see `$table->string('role_id')->unsigned();` anywhere in OPs code.

Comment: `$table->unsignedInteger('role_id');` is the equivalent of `$table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();` though

Comment: yup...I tried the both way also got same error, except I remove the foreign key. Is that problem related with model ?

Comment: Referring to the API they are not equivalent. The unsigned() function used turn an given type to unsigned. The unsignedInteger() function turns the integer to a 4-Byte long int. Primary Keys are even stored as 4 byte int. So with using the unsignedInt you can maybe provide a length problem over there.

Comment: @user10354117 it might be, that the type of role_id is not an integer ? can you check that up in the database and maybe post the sql structure of the related user_role table ?

Comment: I just add the code for user_role table. I still doubt it what the problem was.

Comment: @user10354117 Your table is named wrong in the foreign key assignment. It needs to be 'user_roles'. See my updated anweser

Comment: Ohh!!!! Finally found the answer of it! I tried to migrate for the user_roles table 1st and then migrate user table again. It works! I refer from this url: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20532430/general-error-1005-when-creating-a-key-constraint-laravel

Comment: Okay, that was a problem we could not identify because the migrations code was missing. 
Could you mark the answer as the correct one related to your problem? Because the order of the migrations does not refer directly to the question you were asking, and so others can earn profit of the naming mistake you got over there?

Comment: @user10354117 i also edited my post, so future users can check that problem

Comment: Yup! Thanks you so much! Learn alot :)

Answer (score 0):

This issue is obscure. It may also happen if the type of reference column and foreign key column is different.

for e.g: if the foreign key column was `SMALLINT(5)` UNSIGNED and the referenced column was `INT(10)` UNSIGNED.

Comment: Checked. Both of them are using int(10). So I think not this issue.

Answer (score 0):

IN your code here:

```
       $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('user_role')->onDelete('cascade');
```

you are refereeing to **user_role** table but you do not have this table, you have **user_roles** table so make user_role to user_roles

```
       $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('user_roles')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Hope this solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

table name you are passing is incorrect. It should be `user_roles` not `user_role` as you have created table named `user_roles`

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('user_roles')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```